# Different in Java SHA1 vs JavaScript SHA1

Tags: java, javascript, hash, sha1

I am a little bit confused. I want to get the bytes of an String, which is hashed with SHA1.

JavaScript:

```
var content = "somestring";
console.warn(content.getBytes().toString());
console.warn(CryptoJS.SHA1(content.getBytes().toString()).toString().getBytes());

String.prototype.getBytes = function () {
var bytes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
    bytes.push(this.charCodeAt(i));
}
return bytes;
};

Array.prototype.toString = function(){
var result = "";
for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
    result += this[i].toString();
}
return result;
}
```

which gives me

```
115111109101115116114105110103
[52, 99, 97, 54, 48, 56, 99, 51, 53, 54, 102, 54, 48, 53, 50, 49, 99, 51, 49, 51, 49, 100, 49, 97, 54, 55, 57, 55, 56, 55, 98, 52, 52, 52, 99, 55, 57, 102, 54, 101]
```

Java:

```
String message = "somestring";
byte[] sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1").digest(message.getBytes());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(message.getBytes()));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sha1));
System.out.println(new String(sha1));
```

which gives me

```
[115, 111, 109, 101, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103]
[-38, 99, -5, 105, -82, -80, 60, 119, 107, -46, 62, -111, -30, -63, -53, 61, -13, 1, 53, -45]
Úcûi®°<wkÒ>‘âÁË=ó5Ó
```

The first output is equal on JavaScript and Java, but the second is different. Why and how is a checksum like `Úcûi®°<wkÒ>‘âÁË=ó5Ó` possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution:

Javascript:

```
key = 'testKey';
var hashedKey = CryptoJS.SHA1(key);
console.log(hashedKey);
```

Output: 2420e186fcdb8d0ea08d82fdfbfb8722d6cbf606

Java:

```
password="testKey";
final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
ByteArrayOutputStream pwsalt = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
pwsalt.write(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
byte[] unhashedBytes = pwsalt.toByteArray();
byte[] digestVonPassword = md.digest(unhashedBytes);
System.out.println(bytesToHex(digestVonPassword));
```

Output: 2420E186FCDB8D0EA08D82FDFBFB8722D6CBF606

With the exceptions of capital vs. lowercase, the output is the same.  It's in hex, by the way.

Comment: Yeah I figured it yesterday out. The problem in Java is byte is limited (2^8) signed. 128 is -128, 129 is -127 ... and 255 is -1.
In JavaScript there isn't this "problem".

Answer (score 2):

In your *JavaScript* you're doing a *SHA-1* on a *String* which is the numbers from a byte *Array* (so is different to your *String* `content`).

```
console.warn(CryptoJS.SHA1(content.getBytes().toString()).toString().getBytes());
//                                              ^^
```

In your *Java*, you're doing a *SHA-1* on a `byte[]` (which is equivalent to your *String* `content`)

```
byte[] sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1").digest(message.getBytes());
//                                                                ^^
```

Your `toString` is creating a very different piece of data to what you're *SHA-1*-ing in *Java*.

Also (not sure if relevant): internally, *JavaScript* uses *UTF-16* for *Strings*.

---

Further, the logged output of your *JavaScript* cannot be a *SHA-1* as it is the wrong length; this is due to `.toString().getBytes()` repeated on the `sha1` after it's been calculated ([*Stephen C*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139985/stephen-c) mentions this in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355421/#comment25184756_17355487)).

Comment: The problem is CryptoJS.SHA1 supports only string. I thought, it would be fine if I just convert it to byte array and then into string.

Comment: @Niklas - Obviously not!. Use some other Javascript library to compute the hashes!  Or change `CryptoJS.SHA1(content.getBytes().toString()).toString().getBytes()` to `CryptoJS.SHA1(content).toString().getBytes()

Comment: I commented my prototype toString function and also tried both function calls. Neither of them work.

Comment: Hashes are incredibly sensitive to their inputs ... and rightly so.  Any difference in the input, no matter how small, will result in a different hash.  You need to arrange that the bytes that go into the algorithm are EXACTLY the same, if you want the output hashes to match.

Comment: And looking at the SHA1 *output* from the JS version, the fact that all of the bytes are positive is too strange to be a coincidence.  It looks like you are also mangling the hash *after* the SHA1 computation with your `toString().getBytes()` "transformation".

Comment: If I am reconstructing a string with the byte array `new String(sha1)` This comes out: `Úcûi®°<wkÒ>‘âÁË=ó5Ó` How could this be a sha1?

Comment: In _JavaScript_, the reverse of `String.prototype.charCodeAt` is `String.fromCharCode` (though you have to do it one char at a time). Your `sha1` should be an _Array_ or something similar though, and _JavaScript_ consoles have no problem logging these in a human-readable way already.

Comment: The problem in Java is byte is limited (2^8) signed. 128 is -128, 129 is -127 ... and 255 is -1. In JavaScript there isn't this "problem".

Answer (score 0):

I found this library. It produces same values as Java

https://caligatio.github.io/jsSHA/