# Sha1( ) returning different outputs in Java and Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, encoding, hash, sha1

I am implementing a part of my Java project in Javascript, and I am currently in the part where hashes and authentication stuff happen. I have a java class here:

```
import com.google.common.hash.Hashing;

import static com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding.base64;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

public class SampleTest {
    public static void main(String arg[]){
        String payLoad = "payload";
        System.out.println(     base64().encode(    Hashing.sha1().hashString(payLoad, UTF_8).asBytes()    )    );
    }

}
```

It prints out `MMrWAYjQdoQyEgTVAvYUEiWQQ2g=`

And next, I try to do this in Javascript using CryptoJS:

```
<script>
    var hash = CryptoJS.SHA1("payLoad");
    var base = btoa(hash)
    document.write(base);
</script>
```

This outputs `MzBjYWQ2MDE4OGQwNzY4NDMyMTIwNGQ1MDJmNjE0MTIyNTkwNDM2OA==`.

I am a noob when it comes to hashing/encoding stuff right now, so can someone please throw some light? Why are they outputting different stuff?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked out this post? http://stackoverflow.com/q/17355421/2459730

Comment: `payload` vs `payLoad`, perhaps

Comment: Nope, I changed it to payLoad in both, but they're still different. What java prints out for "payLoad" has been updated.

Comment: ah, wild guess. @Andrew_CS's link looks promising though